# Designing my first database schema: suggestion needed

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is my first database schema design. I am trying to develop a small web application for my department which will be used for food cost management. And I am doing this for my learning purpose.

**How the food cost management works in my department:**

1. Total members: 15
2. One admin to keep record of all the cost. he will update the database on a daily basis.
3. Each member can order only once a day. If anyone has guest on any specific day he can order multiple number of meal.
4. Usually members pay their bill for a week or two in advance.
5. one or two persons are responsible for bringing the food from outside and they don't  need to pay for their lunch. Transportation cost is also given to them. their food cost+ transportation cost is distributed equally to other 15 members expenses.

**Database queries:**

**From admin perspective:**

1. he will manage/add the daily order. (Table: orders)
2. he will add the payments for all the members which will be credited against respective member's "Balance" (Table: payments)
3. he will be able to see an overview of all members' order/cost history and their current balance in a chart for one month at a time.
4. If any member has negative balance or less than a specific amount of money, it will be notified to admin dashboard.

**From member perspective:**

1. he will be able to see his current balance and order/cost history for last one month at a time.
2. he will be able to see last x number of payment history he made.

Based on the queries I mentioned above I tried to design a database schema which looks like the diagram below:

[image: database schema diagram]

**Elaboration of some attributes:**

*EPlatenum*: Number of extra plate of food brought besides number of plate ordered.

*Eplatecost*: cost for extra plate of food. this cost is distributed equally among 15members individual cost.

*EPersonnum* & *EPersoncost*: Number of extra person involved in bringing the food and their total cost. the cost will be distributed equally among 15members individual cost.

*TransCost*: transportation cost. the cost will be distributed equally among 15members individual cost.

**Questions:**

1. what are the mistakes I have made and how can I overcome them?
2. For my DailyList table I have used "date" as the primary key.Is it OK to use date as primary key? IF not OK, what can be the primary key here instead?
3. when I am going to populate a chart overview for 30 months cost/order history the database query will be huge I assume. what approach should I take to optimize the query?

I am looking forward to getting your suggestions on improving the database schema. Please help me correcting my design mistakes and overcome them. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: From quickly looking at your schema, you should **never** store money as float as they have limited precision and may not be accurate (e.g 0.99 instead of 1). I would suggest changing the data type of any column that stores money as DECIMAL or NUMERIC as they are fixed point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

My first impression:

1. I think payment should be related to order (because user pays for specific order).
2. I don't know what DailyList is, but if there may be more than two with the same date (and as I can image it may be) you shouldn't use it as a primari key.
3. Password should be encoded with e.g. SHA (so varchar 15 is to less).

Comment: 2. Daily list is actually DailyCostList for other expenses i.e number of extra persons and total cost for their food, number of extra plate of food and their cost are included here. there will be one record for each date and not more than that.

Comment: So it's perfectly fine to be a primary key

Comment: 1. Payments are paid in advance for one week or two. These amount will be added to their respective balance field in "user" table. for tracking individual meal cost there is one attribute "OrderCost" in "orders" table

Comment: OK, so that is fine. Another clue, do not use "float" for prices. You should use decimal format (just a good practice, because of floating point precision problems).